# Set ListView height for device height

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, height

i want to listview's height should change for device height.

text and button in top, listview in center, mediaplayer buttons in bottom.

this should be a very easy thing to do, but it looks like it's very mixed. 
my layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchButton2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/searchResult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="306dp" >

    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/timeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/init_time"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/playerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/prevButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/prev"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_media_previous" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/playButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/play"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_media_play" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/pause"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_media_pause" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/stopButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/stop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_media_stop" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/next"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_media_next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using this code:

```
    searchText2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.searchText2);
    searchButton2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.searchButton2);
    searchResult = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.searchResult);
    playerLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.playerLayout);
    timeLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.timeLayout);
    // hide player now
    playerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    timeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    searchResult.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(), R.layout.resulttext, new ArrayList<String>()));
```

listview is center of them. how can i change listview's height for device's height. thank you

edit: fixed like this;

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/searchResult"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/playerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

thanks to @MatusSeidl

Comment: My suggestion is: abandon the `LinearLayout` in favour of a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: thanks for answer but which one?

Comment: The **root** one. By the way, you could **simplify** your design. Such level nesting is **unnecessary and bad** for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to listView add;

```
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="10"
```

and to LinearLayout with buttons, add;

```
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: thanks it works. but warning like this;
Nested weights are bad for performance